# Searching for a pattern in a sentence with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture the digits that follow a certain phrase and also the start and end index of the number of interest.

Here is an example:

```
text = The special code is 034567 in this particular case and not 98675
```

In this example, I am interested in capturing the number `034657` which comes after the phrase `special code` and also the start and end index of the the number `034657`.

My code is:

```
p = re.compile('special code \s\w.\s (\d+)')
re.search(p, text)
```

But this does not match anything. Could you explain why and how I should correct it?

Comment: I think it just doesn't match because your regex requires both a literal space and then a whitespace character (`\s`).

Comment: Use `special\s+code\s+is\s+(\d+)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vkk2Cx/1).

Comment: Also: `\w.` might not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression matches a space and any whitespace with  `\s` pattern, then `\w.` matches any word char and any character other than a line break char, and then again `\s`  requires two whitespaces, any whitespace and a space.

You may simply match any 1+ whitespaces using `\s+` between words, and to match any chunk of non-whitespaces, instead of `\w.`, you may use `\S+`.

Use

```
import re
text = 'The special code is 034567 in this particular case and not 98675'
p = re.compile(r'special code\s+\S+\s+(\d+)')
m = p.search(text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # 034567
    print(m.span(1))  # (20, 26)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/z9kvbR) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q9YtBX/1).

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall` with a capture group:

```
text = "The special code is 034567 in this particular case and not 98675"
matches = re.findall(r'\bspecial code (?:\S+\s+)?(\d+)', text)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['034567']
```

Comment: I need also the position of the number, i.e. start and end index for downstream tasks.

Comment: And why would you need that?

Comment: In your expression (?:...) what it represents?  I.e. ?:

Comment: That is just a pattern for an optional single word between `special code` and the actual number which follows.

Comment: So whatever is after the parenthesis ( followed by ?: and ends to the right parenthesis ) is optional and not captured as a group. The semi-columns are instructing that the group is not to be captured, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  And this leaves the number itself as the one (and only) capture group.  So, what you would get back on a larger text, would just be a single level array of  numbers.